# Intercept incorrect entries in C-program

Tags: c, exception, numbers, multiple-entries

As I started to learn C, I have a question:
I have a programm, where the user has to entry six numbers for a calculation. 
How can I (easily) intercept incorrect entries like characters or less numbers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write some code and show us. Try something. Make an effort.

Comment: Show us what you have so far and what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).